# Android Service, periodically HTTP Request

Tags: php, android, service

I am developing a service to display notifications that I'm going to throw me through a PHP page that accesses a database. I would like to develop a periodic check of the page itself .. With the activity I did with no problems, but with the service application crashes or can not access the web page. How so? This is the code that I use for now:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
 public void onCreate() {   

     super.onCreate();      
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {      

     super.onDestroy();         
 }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {     

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://zackfairsite.altervista.org/test_notifica.php"); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

        is.close(); // Close the stream

         Toast.makeText(this, resString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       

     return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

 }

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {       
     return null;
 }
```

}

Comment: What is the stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: Why are you using Service for making network call, rather extend IntentService. Service runs on main thread where IntentService runs on separate thread. example link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#service_start

Comment: I do not understand .. therefor every I should use the IntentService? Because the Service does not go well, do not initialize the API Web?

Comment: Service is raw implementation, IntentService is kind of extended Service with a built in wrapper which reduces boilerplate code for binding and all. Write all your current API call code in Intent Service and then with the help of Alarm Manager periodically run the Intent Service from Activity. Use broadcast receiver for sending response from API call in service to activity